# How do you use RequireJS in a .NET application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, requirejs

I have the following folder structure:

->custom

- charts

  - ...JS files
- enhance

  - ...JS files
- general

  - ...JS files

->lib

- jquery
- jquery.ui

jquery-1.7.2.js 
requirejs-1.0.7.js 
order.js

I have a .NET application with a lot of ascx control files that reference JS files in the traditional manner by calling a JS file within a script tag and then calling some function from that file.

Question is how should I (or can I) implement Require JS so that I can:

1) call the JS files Last after all images, css and html has been loaded, and...

2) use the AMD concept of modulising the code

It is important to point out that within each aspx file there are up to 5 ascx files and some have ascx controls contained within. A lot of the ascx files have embedded JavaScript inside them, and a lot of the .master pages also have JavaScript file references.

I am unable to change the structure of the web site (as the site is rather large), so I need to find a solution.

Thanks

Comment: Reading your question I can tell you will have a lot of work if you opt to use requirejs. Requirejs a very good tool for web apps, but it is not close to be friendly with non-well-structured-application.

Comment: I am implementing requireJS into a .NET app now with great success, the hard work is converting all the pages that calls javascript and either creating modules for tat call if it holds a large amount of JS code or, wrap the code in a require call. straight forward but yes allot of work to convert the site.

Comment: Check this project [RequireJS .NET](https://github.com/stefanprodan/RequireJSDotNet)

Comment: that is perfect, as we are implementing (starting to implement) an MVC framework for projects that we are building on. I have already converted all the code we have to use requirejs but this takes it a little further and will be of use.

Comment: Update on RequireJS implementation:
With the advent of having allot more client side JS heavy coding required for the select.bestinvest website, requireJS was awesome in enforcing modular coding rather than just a top down approach and putting all in one file.

Even though there was a huge amount of work to convert all the JS to run in and with RequireJS, it was well worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

It's called re-factoring... v. The sometimes painful process of rewriting a previously un-architected solution into a well architected one.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an answer for calling "InvokeScript()" from a .NET web browser control. But Google led me here and somebody might find this useful.

Firstly, define your new AMD module as you would normally. Put whatever you call "InvokeScript()" with as a function inside this module:

```
define (... {
    var mySpecialHandler = function() {
        // do stuff
    };
    return {
      mySpecialHandler: mySpecialHandler
    }
});
```

Then when you come to use it, use the global namespace which is eventually set when the module is loaded:

```
require(['app'], function (app) {
    window.mySpecialHandler = app.mySpecialHandler;
});
```